# OpenGL ES Analyzer for iPad

Tags: ipad, opengl-es-2.0, analyzer

I'm trying to use the OpenGL ES Analyzer for my iPad application and I can't get it to show me any symbols from my code in the extended detail pane's stack trace.  I see the names of UIKit and UIApplication and other Apple supplied frameworks in the stack trace, but the portion of the stack trace that represents calls into my code just shows up as instruction pointer values, and there are no symbols whatever.

When I run the same app in Xcode 4 I can debug into my code without problem, all symbols are there, etc.  So I believe the application is compiled correctly in this regard.

Do others out there have this problem?  The information this analyzer is collecting would be extremely useful if I could see where it my code these calls are being made...

Any pointers / workaround very much appreciated.

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

Well, figured this out myself eventually, so just for completeness and for anyone else who runs into this:

It is necessary to have dSYM debugger output, i.e. "DWARD with dSYM file" in the "Debug Information Format" setting in the project.

I had changed this to be just DWARF as creating the dSYM was taking a long time each build cycle.